# Force GLSurfaceView to full screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I am working on an App that captures the phone camera feed and display it into a GLSurfaceView and then in the renderer I add ImageViews to the screen in some specific coordinates.

The problem I am facing is that the camera feed in the GLSurfaceView is never full screen. In some Android versions it will put some black space horizontally in the top and bottom and in some other versions the black space will be smaller but vertical on the Left and Right of the screen.

I wanted to ask if there is any way to force fullscreen on every version ? I am fairly new to working with GLSurfaceView and nothing I tried works.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a problem of the cameras aspect ratio compared to the screen aspect ratio? If they don't match, you'll either have to have some bars or you zoom in and cut off parts of the video.

Comment: how can I have some bars ?

Comment: I though you already have those black bars?

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood you the first time. I will try to mess with the camera ratio maybe it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into immersive mode to get rid of the system buttons if that's appropriate to your app: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

You should also look into the `android.max_aspect` manifest setting to eliminate black bars on very widescreen devices: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html

You should also look into supporting display cutouts (notches): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout/

As mentioned in the comments by BDL, if the screen and camera aspect ratio don't match, then you are going to have to have black bars, or cut off some content.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help, I wanted to ask if there is any way to mesure the size of the black spaces ?